# Function VS Events Listener

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, dom-events

I have little knowledge on programming and I started exploring node.js.
In one of characteristics of node is that 'Event Driven Architecture'.

While I can understand the idea and the advantages, I am not really getting the difference between that and function.
To keep it as simple as possible I tried to think the difference between a standard function (reusable piece of code that respond to a call) and an Event Listen (reusable piece of code that respond to an event).

Is there anyone who can put some light on this?

Comment: Event listener functions are just functions. There's no inherent difference; a function is a function.

Comment: You can use any function as an event listener, both anonymous and otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in nodejs Javascript work just like all other languages.  They are a piece of reusable code that you can call at any time.  You can make an entire program that just calls functions to get its job done and then exists.

But, most programs written in nodejs respond to outside activity (like a web request or a data being sent over a socket).  For that, you must use an event listener of some kind.  An event listener is really just your code registering an interest in a specific event and assigning a function that will be called whenever that event occurs.  Functions are used for events too (they are just regular functions, but are called "callbacks"), but they are called automatically by some sub-system when an event occurs rather than you calling them directly from your own code.

Let's look at a nodejs webserver based on the Express module:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // this function is called when the webserver gets a request for "/"
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

In this code, the `app.get()` line of code is says that when the web server gets a web request for the path  "/", then call the function that is declared inside of the `app.get()` call.  This particular function is an inline anonymous function, but it is still a function and it doesn't have to be declared that way.  It could be a regular named function too.

So, the above code could also be with a named function like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function rootRouteHandler(req, res) {
  // this function is called when the webserver gets a request for "/"
  res.send('hello world');
}

app.get('/', rootRouteHandler);

app.listen(3000);
```

The execution of these two is no different.  Both are registering a function to be called sometime in the future when a particular event occurs.  In this particular case, usually the preferred design pattern is the anonymous function just because the code is a little more self contained and self documenting and there usually isn't a reason to use a name for the function (it usually isn't called anywhere else).